# Help making 4-5 stage chair recline hinge that you pull forward slightly to drop one stage

Tags: hinge

We are building reclining sitting chairs with a 4-5 stage ratchet backrest.

ISSUE: all the ratchet hinges we can find require the backrest to be pushed all the way down or pulled all the way up before adjusting it to the desired level. This requires the user to sit up or even get out of the seat to adjust

DESIRED SOLUTION: The user can pull the backrest forward 3-5°, and then the backrest will recline one stage. Pulling forward another 3-5° drops it another stage. To return it to the upright position the user grasps the backrest and pulls forward.

Does this type of hinge exist?

[image: Recline]

Comment: `This requires the user to sit up` ... you cannot use a small lever to push the backrest towards the upright position while the user is laying on the backrest ... a force multiplier system or a powered system would be required for that

Comment: Thanks. Ok what if there's no lever, they sit up slightly to pull forward 3-5°, then it drops down one stage. Is that feasible?

Here's a video of a similar mechanism but it requires the backrest to go back the entire way before ratcheting up. 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FQDpmdwNYsk